# Dataset file size in R, possible overhead?

Tags: r

I am useing stat transfer to convert a dataset from SAS file format to R-format. The file in SAS is ~ 489mb, when converted to Rdata its 520mb. Given that the file is a data frame with 4090222 x 11 "cell's", I suppose that the difference can be explained to some extent.

But when I open the converted dataset, and ask R to save it, the 530mb goes down to some 120mb, I really dont understand how and why this is happening. I suspect data is dropped (because the resize is so notable), but as far as I can see, this is not happening.

I have tried all.equal which returns TRUE. In fact everything I try, tells me that the datasets are indeed equal... But it does not add up?

Am I makeing some huge mistake?

EDIT: See Gregors point below, "problem" solved!

Comment: When saving to disk, you use compression.  I don't think there is a big mystery going on.

Comment: See `?save`. If you want a bigger file you can set `compress = F` or set `compression_level` to an integer less than the default of 9.

Comment: See also [this blog entry](http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2014/03/it-is-time-for-rdata-files-to-become.html) comparing the compression of various statistical language's data formats.

Comment: Thanks for the link Gregor, I was concerned about data drops... Nice to know that R is efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turning my comments into an answer:

R compresses data when it saves it as .RData, and actually does an impressive job of it as compared to other statistical programming languages, as demonstrated in [this blog entry](http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2014/03/it-is-time-for-rdata-files-to-become.html).

So the answer is **no**, you shouldn't be worried.